# Python method not recognized

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python so I have worked on this one thing a long time.  I still can't find the answer.

Interpreter says there is no method called _set_icon()

code:

```
import pyodbc as db
import pandas as pd

import Globals

class BatchNodeData(object):
    """support batch node of the tree.  Contains what it needs to do that"""

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def _set_icon():
        sql_conn = db.connect(Globals.SQL_CONN_STRING)
        b_query = " \
              SELECT top 1 * \
                FROM dbo.ETLBatchRun a \
                Where b.BatchID = " + str(batchid) + \
                "Order by a.StatusDT desc"
        df_icon = pd.read_sql(b_query, sql_conn)      
        if not df_icon.empty:
            self.last_status = df_icon['StatusID'].iloc[0]

    def _get_icon_index():
        switcher = {
            1: 2,
            2: 2,
            3: 3,
            4: 4
        }
        switcher_selected = {
            1: 7,
            2: 7,
            3: 8,
            4: 8
        }
        if selected:
            return switcher_selected.get(statusid, 0) # default 0 (yellow bar)
        else:
            return switcher.get(statusid, 0) # default 0 (yellow bar)

    def __init__(self, batchid):
        self.batch_id = None
        self.batch_name = None
        self.critical = None
        self.node_icon_index = None
        self.last_status = None
        self.selected = False
        self.running = False

        sql_conn = db.connect(Globals.SQL_CONN_STRING)
        b_query = " \
              select b.BatchID \
              , b.BatchName \
              , c.AttributeValue as Critical \
              , noRun.AttributeValue as noRun \
              from dbo.ETLBatch b (nolock) \
              left join dbo.etlbatchattribute (nolock) c \
                on c.batchid = b.batchid \
                    and c.AttributeName = 'Critical' \
                    and c.AttributeValue = '1' \
              left join dbo.etlbatchattribute (nolock) noRun \
                on noRun.batchid = b.batchid \
                    and noRun.AttributeName = 'NotRunnableInETLMonitor' \
                    and noRun.AttributeValue = '1' \
              Where b.BatchID = " + str(batchid)
        df_batch = pd.read_sql(b_query, sql_conn)      
        for index, row in df_batch.iterrows():
            batch_id = row['BatchID']
            batch_name = row['BatchName']
            critical = row['Critical']
        _set_icon()
        self.node_icon_index = _get_icon_index()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time to take the [tour], read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]. In questions regarding errors, please post the full Traceback showing all details of the error and where it came from

Comment: Please share the **entire** error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've declared _set_icon() as a method bounded by the class, you should be able to call it as:

```
BatchNodeData._set_icon()
```

Comment: It is an instance method so the right way to call it would be on an instance of the calss and not the class itself (although possible). `b = BatchNodeData(); b._set_icon()`

Comment: The problem is that he is calling the function from inside his __init__

I think maybe self._set_icon() should work

Comment: True. The problem with that is that `_set_icon()` is not even taking `self` as a parameter so that will throw another error